# Is there a way to sync google contacts between two Gmail accounts?

Tags: gmail-contacts

Is there a way to sync google contacts between two Gmail accounts?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that it is possible at this stage without a third party tool (such as [soocial](http://blog.soocial.com/2009/12/30/sync-across-multiple-gmail-accounts/)). However, as painful as it is, you can always perform an export / import between accounts.

Comment: +1 - http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/gmail/thread?tid=2d7fb3b55cdf78a2&hl=en

Comment: soocial is closing soon ! Do you know any replacement ? I found it really useful.